# TFHpple request not running on background thread?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, hpple

this works fine on the main thread but for some reason doesn't work when running on a background thread. If you just comment out the call to dispatch_async than the program works fine!

Code:

```
NSString *requestString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.songlyrics.com/index.php?section=search&searchW=%@+%@&submit=Search",actualSongName,actualSongArtist];
        NSLog(@"0");
        TFHpple *requestParser = [TFHpple hppleWithHTMLData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:requestString]]];
        NSLog(@"1");
        NSString *requestedURLXPathQuery = @"//a";
        NSArray *requestedStringsNodes = [requestParser searchWithXPathQuery:requestedURLXPathQuery];
        NSLog(@"2");
```

This is what gets logged:

```
2012-10-11 21:39:05.636 SuperViewer[6612:110b] 0
2012-10-11 21:39:05.651 SuperViewer[6612:907] Unable to parse.
2012-10-11 21:39:06.520 SuperViewer[6612:110b] 1
2012-10-11 21:39:06.565 SuperViewer[6612:110b] 2
```

This is all running on a background thread. 
Also I have logged the "requestString" var and its fine.

Any ideas what the problem is? 
Does Hpple not run on background threads?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what's your exact issue. However Use [NSThread](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSThread_Class/Reference/Reference.html) instead of using dispatch_async. Make sure to use

```
  -[NSObject performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:]
```

to run on main thread (for Ui interactive functionality)

Comment: This is what I did originally.... So obliviously this doesn't work either. Any other ideas?